# Simple modding function in php and MySQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to make a php code to increment a value in a MySQL table using php.
The value needs to be increased by $howMany which is passed as a parameter. I've ran the mysqli_error and got nothing. I still suspect the issue might be with the query. Any ideas?

CODE:

```
function addPoints($username,$howMany)
{
  define('DB_SERVER','n');
  define('DB_USERNAME','n');
  define('DB_PASSWORD','n');
  define('DB_NAME','n');
  $link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
  $currPoints = obtainPoints($username);
  $currPoints+=$howMany;
  $query = 'UPDATE `users` SET `points` = '.$currPoints.' WHERE `users`.`id=`'.fetchIDByUsername($username);
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
}
```

Comment: what's the error it displays?\

Comment: It doesn't seem to display any errors, and the query looks fine

Comment: ``users``.``id=`` I think this is the issue, because of =` you beginn the ` but don't close it after the equal sign

Comment: Not the issue, it didn't fix it

Comment: Try this: 'UPDATE `users` SET `points` = '.$currPoints.' WHERE `users.id` = '.fetchIDByUsername($username);
Notice stackoverflow converts the `  sign to code

Comment: Why are you using a DEFINE when the definition and usage are both within the scope of the same function? What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Where is the instrumentation in your code to detect errors?

Comment: Holy crap! It worked! @Fabian , could you add your comment as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: @MattiaMarziali I added it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment:

The problem is the `users`.`id=` part.

Try the following:

```
'UPDATE `users` SET `points` = '.$currPoints.' WHERE `users.id` = '.fetchIDByUsername($username);
```